# Cannot call external Model while on server Codeigniter HMVC but works fine on local

Tags: php, codeigniter, cpanel, hmvc

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: RuntimeException
>
> Message: Unable to locate the model you have specified: Impact_model
>
> Filename:
>   /home/appliedi/public_html/multisector.Nutrition.com/system/core/Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 344
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   /home/appliedi/public_html/multisector.Nutrition.com/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php
>   Line: 213 Function: model
>
> File:
>   /home/appliedi/public_html/multisector.Nutrition.com/application/modules/Ministry/controllers/Ministry.php
>   Line: 11 Function: model
>
> File: /home/appliedi/public_html/multisector.Nutrition.com/index.php
>   Line: 315 Function: require_once //error at this line on controller

```
<?php
class Ministry extends MX_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Ministry_model');
        //error i think cant call external controller model
        $this->load->model('Impact/Impact_model');
        //---------------------------------
        $sad = $this->session->all_userdata();
        if(!$sad['checkLogin'] == true)
        {
          redirect( base_url('login') );
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class Ministry extends MX_Controller
{
  function index()
  {
     $this->load->model('Ministry_model');
     $this->load->model('Impact/Impact_model');
     $sad = $this->session->all_userdata();
     if(!$sad['checkLogin'] == true)
     {
         redirect( base_url('login') );
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure all model filename & class name are in capital letters..linux is case sensitive unlike windows ..

Answer (score 0):

On serveryou should follow tha name pattern as:

For Model:

Filename:
mymodel.php

In File:

```
class Mymodel extends CI_Model{
    //code
}
```

For Controller:

Filename:
Mycontroller.php

In File:

```
class Mycontroller extends CI_Controller{
    //code
}
```